# What happens when a cshtml page changes on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razorgenerator

To be more specific, when a `cshtml` is needed, what happens? I would need to build an application with only ashx and a template engine, without the **MVC** stuffs, simple rendering, but i would'not like to loose the capability to change the `cshtml` files on the fly. So I have somehow to manage their recompilation, possibly without recycling the application server loading and unloading `AppDomains`.

On the first request I can build the page and load it in a sort of cache (like **RazorEngine** on codeplex), then reuse it. When the page changes i should change the page and that's it.

But as far as I understood a new `assembly` is built for every page, so if there are frequent changes (that is likely to happens in my environment) tons of assemblies will get loaded.

The question is,

**How it works for the standard MVC ? 
 CodeDom is used, or directly IL that is subsequently added without creating new assemblies?**

One thing that comes me in mind now is that after building the `assembly`, it can be decompiled and then the `IL` loaded directly on the app, that would make sense

Ask for further clarification if it's unclear! (*and any suggestion to this Stackoverflow newbie is welcome*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
First the cshtml files are loaded then the files are compild into their own assemblies with the standard CSharp/VbCodeCompiler, no code dom is present as far as i understood...